# How can I replace an oEmbed URL in post with actual embed HTML

Tags: filters, hooks, embed, twitter, oembed

What I want is to get the output of the Twitter oEmbed system into my actual posts. IMHO the embed output itself is high-quality, semantic HTML and I'd rather have it inside the post than in the embed metadata in case their js stops working (in which case the tweet would display as a sensible blockquote).

So what I need is to hijack the oEmbed system and, upon processing it, replace the embed URL in the post with the HTML from Twitter. Clearly the solution should also be able to handle other kinds of embeds.

UPDATE: Just to be clear, I know how oEmbed works by default (i.e. the URL will be replaced with the oEmbed HTML when the 'the_content' filter is run on the post content) and that is not what I want. What I need is a way to hijack that system and, instead of only having the content replaced at display time, have the embed URL itself replaced inside the post_content in the the database with the HTML returned from the oEmbed provider.

Comment: Did you ever solve this?  Chances are you just need to parse the post content on save and replace the links with the resulting code yourself. There should be regEx to find oEmbed URLs, then another function to force generate the response from the URL. You would only need to swap them at that point. The downside is that 3 years later in the tech world produces a completely different embed usually. So all your hard work will be obsolete at some point.

Answer (score 1):

Check out the [embed API](http://codex.wordpress.org/Embeds), particularly the functions [`wp_oembed_add_provider()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_oembed_add_provider) and [`wp_embed_register_handler()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_embed_register_handler).

What version of WP are you running at the moment? And what happens when you place a Twitter URL on its own line in plain text? 3.4+ should handle embeds, never tried it myself.

Comment: I updated the question to clarify why this answer doesn't help. Twitter is already a built-in oEmbed provider so I don't need to register them. What I want is a reliable way to replace the embed URL with the embed HTML inside the post content in the database, rather than only having it replaced at load time.

Comment: Gotcha. Are you aware that WP caches oEmbed responses as transients, so it's not as resource-intensive as you might think?

Answer (score -3):

This will be copyright violation and it is very not recommended to do from a legal perspective.

From a technical perspective, embeded code many times uses "external" resources like JS and CSS that might load in the context of an iframe but not in the context of your site.

So, it is both a legal and technical mine field which you probably should not even attempt to step in.

Comment: Copyright violation: interesting but not at all important to me. The site I was asking about is twitter, who offer the same code to copy/paste on their site so I'm not worried. And even if they didn't, copyright is triggered when WP caches the content in a transient, so saving it in the post itself doesn't change anything.

Comment: Re: JavaScript - also not relevant. The script loaders are in the oembed output so they would be in the post (again, just like if I had pasted it from their site). I would have to be careful about the visual editor of course and make sure the code is stable there (once again, same as if it was pasted in). In the twitter case what I want to save is their elegant block quote format, which works great even without any JavaScript.

Comment: 1. it is a copyright violation. 2. no the oembed will give you an iframe in all sane cases, the iframe will include css or js that if they work might interact negatively with your site

Comment: If you're a copyright lawyer you can try to prove that it's somehow a violation to copy the oembed output from the transient into the post content, otherwise I'm not interested in your attempts to do so.

Comment: You are wrong about the Twitter oEmbed output and/or you consider Twitter insane, not really interested in which it is.

Comment: It is not your tweets, it is not your html therefor you need a license to use it. And yes I am not a lawyer but I spent time studying copyright issues. You do not need an explicit license for using oembed because all you add to your content is an iframe which is equivalent to linking to something and ruled in must countries to not to be a copyright violation.

Comment: even stupid wordpress adds JS to the oembed it provides, but I guess facts do not matter much to you.

Comment: When WP fetches the oEmbed output from Twitter it gets back a blockquote and a script tag for a JS file. It saves that text in a transient and inserts it in the post during wp_content filter. When a user copies and pastes the embed code from Twitter they get the same text, which they are encouraged to paste into the post. Copying the oEmbed output into the post is the same copyright-wise as copying it from the Twitter site into your post.

Comment: In theory, other sites might offer things only via oEmbed, which would make it more complicated, but either way, whatever you offer over oEmbed you are expecting people to take and copy into their site. If you want to protect that content you make it an iframe and thus the embed code doesn't have the content, so you are protecting it. Twitter doesn't do this, they give it all away in both oEmbed and copy/paste embed code. There is no reason to think Twitter expects us to treat the oEmbed code differently than the copy/paste code.

Comment: you are confusing the oenbed code and the html/dom generated at the browser. oEmbed providers let you copy some small code onto your server, but do not let you copy the entire image/video/text that will be served. You have an implicit or maybe even explicit permission to use the code, but no permission to serve the content from your server

Comment: Hey Mark, did you ever look at the Twitter oEmbed code I've described over and over to you? It has the tweet content and a link to the tweet in a blockquote, like I've described over and over. It's not an iframe, it's HTML designed to work without the help of JS, like I've described over and over.